# Creating an add user interface using Aws Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I want to make an app that main user can add other low privilege users(by their mail address). I made a cognito interface for signup but the user can not add another users. What kind of structure is suitable for this kind of job in aws?

Answer (score 0):

Check https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminCreateUser.html

A small example in Java:

```
private static final AWSCognitoIdentityProvider COGNITO = AWSCognitoIdentityProviderClientBuilder.defaultClient();

@Override
public String execute(CreateCognitoUserRequest input, Context context) {
    AdminCreateUserResult result = COGNITO.adminCreateUser(new AdminCreateUserRequest()
            .withUsername(input.getEmail())
            .withUserAttributes(getUserAttributes(input))
            .withUserPoolId(System.getenv("COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID")));
    return result.getUser().toString();
}

private List<AttributeType> getUserAttributes(CreateCognitoUserRequest input) {
    ArrayList<AttributeType> attributes = new ArrayList<>();
    attributes.add(new AttributeType().withName("email").withValue(input.getEmail()));
    attributes.add(new AttributeType().withName("email_verified").withValue("true"));
    attributes.add(new AttributeType().withName("phone_number").withValue(input.getPhoneNumber()));
    attributes.add(new AttributeType().withName("custom:role").withValue(input.getRole()));
    return attributes;
}
```